# Some function for preparing string on Typescript There is a need for a more elegant solution

Tags: javascript

I have a function for preparing string for a search query. But it looks so difficult  There is a need for a more elegant solution. Maybe someone can take a look and provide something better?
It is original func.

```
export const transformedSortFunc = (sortingPath) => {
  let transformPath;
  if (sortingPath) {
    if (sortingPath[0] === '-') {
      const sortingValue = get(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath.slice(1));
      transformPath = sortingValue ? `-${sortingValue}` : undefined;
    } else {
      transformPath = get(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath);
    }
  }
  return transformPath || sortingPath;
};

const SORTING_PATH_MAP = {
    asset: 'asset.type'
}
```

Input parameters can be

```
  const conditional = [
        'id', 'asset', 'conditional', '-id', '-asset', '-conditional' ,
    ]
```

I am using lodash.

For some incoming lines, I need to add a continuation.
For some, no. Lines can be with a minus, so I added additional checks. It ends up looking very complicated

Comment: That looks like Typescript, not Javascript.

Comment: @connexo only the `: string` is TS which is hardly relevant anyway.

Comment: I suggest you remove that from your example then.

Comment: You are right. That was typescript. But it does not matter for this implementation.  But anyway I removed the type declaration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a different organization:

```js
const transformedSortFunc = (sortingPath) => {
  if (!sortingPath) return sortingPath;

  const negative = sortingPath[0] === '-' ? '-' : '';
  const sortingValue = negative ? sortingPath.slice(1) : sortingPath;

  const transformPath = get(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingValue);
  return transformPath ? `${negative}${transformPath}` : sortingPath;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you?

```
tsf=s=>SORTING_PATH_MAP[(s??"").replace(/^-/,"")] ?? s;
```

`tsf()` will remove an optional leading `-` while looking in `SORTING_PATH_MAP` and will use the result if it exists, otherwise it will return `s` directly.

Comment: It looks great, but the case with a "minus" from a constant needs to be slightly modified does not work.
But thanks for the idea, I think I'll work in this direction